# Using DISTINCT or COUNT to "renumber" values in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The code I've compiled so far works perfect...

```
SELECT        CNS_PID, CNS_BID, CNS_SECT_NUM, CNS_USRFLD_220 as OCC_CODE, CNS_USRFLD_220_DESC as OCC_DESC, CNS_EXT_WALL_1_DESC, CNS_STORIES, CNS_GRADE,CNS_AREA_EFFECTIVE,CNS_AREA_GROSS,CNS_AREA_LIVING,
CNS_STYLE,CNS_STYLE_DESC,Null as ROOF_TYPE,CNS_USRFLD_215_DESC as ROOF_COVER,CAST(CNS_WALL_HEIGHT AS varchar)as INT_WALL_HEIGHT_OR_TYPE,CNS_NUM_UNITS
FROM            REAL_PROP.CONSTRCOM 
UNION
SELECT        CNS_PID, CNS_BID, CNS_SECT_NUM, CNS_USRFLD_101, CNS_USRFLD_101_DESC, CNS_EXT_WALL_1_DESC, CNS_STORIES, CNS_GRADE,CNS_AREA_EFFECTIVE,CNS_AREA_GROSS,CNS_AREA_LIVING,
CNS_STYLE,CNS_STYLE_DESC,CNS_ROOF_STRUCT_DESC,CNS_ROOF_COVER_DESC,CNS_INT_WALL_1_DESC,Null as CNS_NUM_UNITS
FROM            REAL_PROP.CONSTRRES
```

However, when it returns records with the same CNS_PID, but different CNS_BID, is there a way to "renumber" those sequentially, like so? (For records with only 1 CNS_BID, I assume the solution will always return "1")

[image: RESULTS]

I've tried DISTINCT and COUNT, but it errors due to no "GROUP BY" clause, which I can't get to work with the UNION.
If there's no way to do this, that's ok, I was just wanting to "clean up" the results a bit, to make it obvious at a glance that there are 3 CNS_BID numbers for that record (and others like it.)

EDIT - ALMOST THERE, BUT NOT QUITE:
I replaced CNS_BID in the SELECT statement with. ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CNS_PID ORDER BY CNS_PID) and it works when there are distinct values in CNS_BID, but it doesn't work if CNS_BID occasionally repeats, which it can because a BID (buidling) can have multiple sections (CNS_SECT_NUM)

HERE'S MY RESULTS... (BUILD_NUM)

| CNS_PID | CNS_BID | BUILD_NUM | CNS_SECT_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2656 | 2656 | 1 | 1 |
| 2656 | 2656 | 2 | 2 |
| 2656 | 2656 | 3 | 3 |
| 2656 | 170166 | 4 | 1 |
| 2656 | 170166 | 5 | 2 |
| 2656 | 170167 | 6 | 1 |
| 2656 | 170167 | 7 | 2 |
| 2656 | 170168 | 8 | 1 |
| 2656 | 170168 | 9 | 2 |

HERE'S WHAT I NEED... (BUILD_NUM)

| CNS_PID | CNS_BID | BUILD_NUM | CNS_SECT_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2656 | 2656 | 1 | 1 |
| 2656 | 2656 | 1 | 2 |
| 2656 | 2656 | 1 | 3 |
| 2656 | 170166 | 2 | 1 |
| 2656 | 170166 | 2 | 2 |
| 2656 | 170167 | 3 | 1 |
| 2656 | 170167 | 3 | 2 |
| 2656 | 170168 | 4 | 1 |
| 2656 | 170168 | 4 | 2 |

Again, if there's no way to do this, that's fine, I will just be stuck with CNS_BID as the identifier, it's just not as orderly and intuitive.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: And try `row_number()`

Comment: @DaleK - row_number() returns results, but not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You must be using it wrong then, show your attempt.

Comment: @DaleK
I replaced CNS_BID in the SELECT statement with...
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CNS_PID ORDER BY CNS_PID)
and it works, thanks!  Your reply pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @DaleK - Damn, actually it didn't work for all cases.  I'll edit my question asap.

Comment: @DaleK - I've edited and formatted as called for, and it looked fine in the preview.  I have no idea what I've done wrong.

Comment: You need a space before and after your markdown table.

Comment: I would revert your changes and ask a new question, because what you are asking is significantly different to your original question. And I would then ensure your questions contains a [mre] with full sample data, and desired results and your attempt. With emphasis on minimal, i.e. remove all the columns that are irrelevant to the problem you are asking about. And for bonus points i.e. a quick answer, provide a DBFiddle so people can play around without having to type all your data in.

Comment: @DaleK - thanks for your help, but I think I'm just going to have to give up on this.  I tried the DB-Fiddle, but even when I follow the guidelines exactly, I get "Schema Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 22
(Even though line 22 is no different than the 21 lines above it)

Comment: @DaleK - I will make one last-ditch effort and take your suggestion to post as a new question.

Comment: Well you need to choose a SQL server fiddle not a mysql fiddle as they are quite different database engines.

Comment: @DaleK- I honestly didn't know which one to choose, and I was too embarrassed to ask.  I'm using Microsoft Server Management Studio v18.10, and I don't know EXACTLY which SQL it uses.  When I find code snippets to try, it's often trial and error for me.